# how to update using updateChildren

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem this is my database

Database JSON:

[image]

what is marked in red is what I have to change, the problem is that the way I am doing it, I only change the above, is what is marked with blue.

How can I change the red? I attach my current code

```
btn_guardarD.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FirebaseDatabase database2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                DatabaseReference myRef2 = database2.getReference("Denuncias").child(uid);
                myRef2.orderByChild("id").equalTo(did).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        String iddenuncia=snapshot.;
                        Map<String,Object> denunciamap = new HashMap<>();
                        denunciamap.put("estado_denuncia","Revision");
                        myRef2.child(iddenuncia).updateChildren(denunciamap);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });

            }
        });
```

adapter class
this is the adapter class from where I get the did that I use to search in the class DetailActivity_encargado

the did is the id of the Denuncias

```
package com.example.denuncia.adapter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.example.denuncia.DetalleActivity;
import com.example.denuncia.DetalleActivity_encargado;
import com.example.denuncia.Login_Activity;
import com.example.denuncia.R;
import com.example.denuncia.model.Denuncia;
import com.example.denuncia.model.Usuarios;
import com.example.denuncia.perfil_Activity;
import com.example.denuncia.perfil_Activity_encargado;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.List;
//para visualizar la lista de denuncias y cargarlas
public class DenunciaAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DenunciaAdapter.DenunciaHolder> {
    List<Denuncia> list;
    int layout;
    Activity activity;
    FirebaseAuth auth;

    public DenunciaAdapter(List<Denuncia> list, int layaut, Activity activity) {
        this.list = list;
        this.layout = layaut;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public DenunciaHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(layout,parent,false);
        return new DenunciaHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DenunciaHolder holder, int position) {
        Denuncia denuncia = list.get(position);

        holder.txttipo.setText(denuncia.getTipo_denuncia());
        holder.txtdireccion.setText(denuncia.getDireccion());
        holder.txtnombre.setText(denuncia.getTitulo_denuncia());
        holder.txtestado.setText(denuncia.getEstado_denuncia());
        holder.txtfecha.setText(denuncia.getFecha());
        holder.txtdetalle.setText(denuncia.getDenuncia_detalles());
        holder.txtid.setText(denuncia.getId());
        Glide.with(activity).load(denuncia.getUrl()).into(holder.imagen);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {return list.size(); }

    public class DenunciaHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView txtnombre,txtdireccion,txtestado,txttipo,txtdetalle,txtfecha,bitmap,txtid;
        ImageView imagen;
        RelativeLayout container;
        public DenunciaHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txttipo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tipo);
            txtid = itemView.findViewById(R.id.denuncia_id);
            txtdetalle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.descripcion);
            txtdireccion = itemView.findViewById(R.id.direccionDenuncia);
            txtestado = itemView.findViewById(R.id.estadoDenuncia);
            txtnombre = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nombreDenuncia);
            txtfecha= itemView.findViewById(R.id.fecha);
            imagen = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_item);


            container = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_container);

            container.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                    String uid = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Encargado");
                    //hace la verificacion si la cuenta es de encargado o usuario y redirecciona a su respectivo perfi
                    myRef.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(uid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(activity, DetalleActivity_encargado.class);
                                intent.putExtra("ID",txtid.getText().toString());
                                activity.startActivity(intent);
                            } else {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(activity, DetalleActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("ID",txtid.getText().toString());
                                activity.startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                        }
                    });

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the `did` coming from? Can you add `Log.d("TAG", did)` before running the realtime db query and share the output?

Comment: Most likely the value of `did` is equal to the one in the blue child, and not in the red one, right?

Comment: there add the two classes you use complete

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks alright to me. The only thing you need to get right is to get the proper `did`. That one is showing to the wrong `uid` in your list.

The fact that you change something says that your code works just on the wrong place. Share a little bit more code with us. Especially where you define `did` and we can solve this.

Comment: there add the two classes you use complete